# Camera Remote API : sample for .Net C# on Windows 7 for QX10

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Do we have .Net C# sample to access sony lens style camera(QX10) using Camera Remote API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this: https://github.com/kazyx/kz-remote-api

It is a .NET wrapper around the HTTP based Camera Remote API.

Comment: thank you @teepee SONY , looks like this library has references specific to Windows 8. (Windows.Networking;Windows.Foundation;Windows.Networking.Connectivity;)

Comment: was able to connect and capture images on my windows 7 machine, with few modifications. thanks @teepee SONY and special thanks to kazyx on github for the library.

Comment: Is there any update regarding a DotNet SDK meanwhile?